# Control statements vs &&, ||

Tags: bash

Is there any difference (performance, compatibility, good practices, etc) between using

```
if [[ condition ]]
then do something
fi
```

vs using something like

```
[[ condition ]] && statement that executes if condition=true
```

or

```
[[ condition ]] || echo 'error'
```

I've been using the latter construction because it saves some space. It's not verbose, but I think it's clear enough what my intentions are.

But my question is whether there is a difference besides verbosity. If I had to construct a more complex statement, then, using the second style, I would have to nest some brackets within others, which becomes hard to read. It's much easier to have nested if statements (due to most people using indentation, etc). Is that the only benefit of using if, elif, fi?

Comment: Just how tiny is your hard drive that you need to save a few bytes of space? The second variant can actually be more readable if you're used to the "guard clause" style, so go with that if it is, but you're not really going to win meaningful performance from a shell to begin with.

Comment: Ok, so nothing about space and performance. What about corner cases? What about readability? What are the arguments in general for using one vs the other?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `&&` and `||` are intended for isolated use (i.e., don't chain them like `a && b || c`; the precedence isn't what you expect) with simple commands. If you find yourself writing something like `a && { b; c; d; }`, use an `if` statement.

Comment: Those criteria sound subjective and fluffy. Use whichever one works right for what you want to do; if they both work use which one you like best. I can't imagine what a definitive "answer" here would be, it's implausible anyone can fill in all the edge cases. It's like asking "how does `return` work."

Comment: Not using `a && b || c` is objective (if `a` succeeds but `b` fails, `c` is executed, despite the intention that `c` be executed only if `a` fails. The "correct" form is `{ a && b; } || c`), but beyond that, yes it is to a large degree a matter of opinion.

Comment: In the "correct" form, `c` is still executed if `b` fails. The "correct-correct" form is really `if a; then b; else c; fi`

Comment: or `a && { b; true;} || c`, but not easy to read

Comment: @chepner But Bash evaluates your example `a && b || c` in the same way as any other programming language. JavaScript: `true && false || function(){console.debug("c")}()`; Scheme: `(or (and #t #f) (display "c\n"))`. It is fine to evaluate `c`, if `a` succeeds and `b` fails.

Comment: It is not trivial to find the right boolean expression for an `if then else` clause. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478713/can-these-nested-if-then-else-be-turned-into-a-boolean-formula

Answer (score 0):

Possibly more on topic for Code Review, but:

The `if`-`then` form is most useful when `do something` is more than one command, or when you need an `else` branch.

The short-circuit versions are well understood, and chainable.  It's mainly a style question than a real programming one.

Many of my shell scripts begin with

```
die() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Then I can write tests such as:

```
test -d "$2" || die "$0: $2 is not a directory"
test -r "$2" && test -x "$2" || die "$0: $2 cannot be read"
```